# Variable binding in Aurelia results in no-undef ESLint error

Tags: javascript, aurelia, eslint

When using Aurelia's `@bindable` decorator on a variable in a custom element, ESLint complains that the variable is not defined.

```
import { bindable } from "aurelia-framework";

export class Logo {
  @bindable click;    // eslint will error on this line with no-undef

  ...
}
```

I assume the `bindable` decorator will define the variable in the class, but is there something that should be done to avoid this ESLint error without including an `eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define` comment on that line?

Running my linter gives me:

```
/src/resources/elements/logo.js
7:15  error  'click' is not defined                             no-undef
```

Comment: try `@bindable() click;`

Comment: @avrahamcool Thanks for the suggestions, but I just tried that and it results in the same eslint error

Comment: maybe do `@bindable click = undefined;`?